# Calculate alpha from $\alpha + \sin(\alpha)$ = K

Tags: trigonometry

Sorry for the dumb question, but I'm not involved in math.
I need to reverse the following formula, to calculate $\alpha$:

$$a = b(\alpha + \sin \alpha)/c$$

So I have:

$$(\alpha + \sin \alpha)=ac/b = K$$

Since $a$, $b$, $c$ are constant, I put equal to $K$.

$\alpha$ is measured in radians. I need to find the value of $\alpha$ (in radians or degree).

Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "closed-form" solution to this equation.  You can use numerical methods to solve it for any given value of $K$.  If $K$ is small,  you can use a series:

$$\alpha = {\frac {1}{2}}K+{\frac {1}{96}}{K}^{3}+{\frac {1}{1920}}{K}^{5}+{\frac {43}{1290240}}{K}^{7}+{\frac {223}{92897280}}{K}^{9} + \ldots $$

The error in the approximation using the terms above is less than about $2 \times 10^{-7}$ for $-1 \le K \le 1$.

Comment: Unfortunately K is at list $300 \cdot 600$. But thanks, you remembered me the use of series!

Comment: @Tommaso: A similar series can be used in other ranges of $K$.  If you write $\alpha = 2 n \pi + t$, $\alpha + \sin(\alpha) = 2 n \pi + t + \sin(t) = K$ if $t + \sin(t) = K - 2 n \pi$.  So if $K$ is near $2 n \pi$, use my series with $K$ replaced by $K - 2 n \pi$ and then add $2 n \pi$ to the result.

Comment: @Tommaso: If $K$ is that big, the approximation $\alpha \approx K$ shouldn't be too bad...

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for the suggestion! I will try to create a code in order to get at least an approximation of the solution

Answer (score 4):

These are what we call Transcendental Equations.

Solving these involve graphical or numerical analysis, both of which yield approximate results.

In graphical analysis, you first rearrange the equation as:

$\sin\alpha = K - \alpha $

Now, on a graph, plot the curve $y=\sin\alpha$. On the same graph, plot the straight line $y=K-\alpha$

The point at which the two intersect is basically the solution of the equation. From the $y$ coordinate of the intersection point, you can then easily calculate the value of $\alpha$ using $y=K-\alpha$

Numeric solutions involve methods like the Newton Raphson Method, Bisection Method, etc.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) is a nice wikipedia article enlisting all such methods.

Answer (score 1):

A useful link with a useful terminology as well

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

This equation is often present in the mathematical problems of celestial mechanics

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the root of the equation $f(\alpha) = \sin(\alpha) + \alpha - K$. Just use Newton-Raphson to get to the solution. If your $K$ is fairly small, then initializing Newton-Raphson with $\frac{K}{2}$ should be good and if its quite large, then initializing $\alpha$ with $K$ should do.